# Работы с файлом С

Tags: c, файлы

Здравствуйте! У меня есть файл в котором хранится код объекта и стоимость выполненной работы на этом объекте, вот такого формата:

> 1
>
> 1300.0
>
> 2
>
> 2000.0
>
> 1
>
> 16000.0
>
> 3
>
> 1400.0
>
> 2
>
> 1800.0

Мне нужно получить новый файл, который складывал все работы для каждого объекта. Для этого примера на выходе должно получится это:

> 1
>
> 17300.0
>
> 2
>
> 3800.0
>
> 3
>
> 1400.

Наталкните на мысль, как это реализовать?

Comment: если объекты - целые числа, используйте их как индексы массива и складывайте при чтении

Comment: Взять какую-нибудь готовую реализацию [map](https://github.com/soywod/c-map).

Comment: Главное — ни в коем случае не используйте float или подобные типы здесь. Деньги -- это всегда целочисленный тип!